# Where can I find rules for constructing DDL commands from ERD?

Tags: ddl, erd

Is there anywhere list of the rules to convert ERD to DDL commands? I don't want to do it in an intuitive way; I need all-cases-handling rules, so I could write code that will do it.

(I **don't** want **tool** that do this; I want the rules to be so generic and handle all cases, that even stupid computer (with samrt programmer) could do it himself while it following the rules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some info about it: http://www.javaguicodexample.com/erdrelationalmodelnotes.html.